# VBA on Excel to delete cells with no color and neighbour cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2007

So I try to figure out a way to do the following trick using VBA:

Assuming we got a huge Excel file.

C500 has some text. 
M500 has a value and it can either have a color fill, or just being a default white cell with a number.
What I want to achieve, is to delete C500 AND M500 when M500 has no color fill.

I know it is a simple task, at least it looks like that and I know that it can probably be solved just by a few lines of code. I still can't find what I need on google or stack overflow by searching for it, probably because of my poor searching skills or because what I wanna do is very specific.

Any help will be deeply appreciated and I will really love to see any similar macro websites out there that I can use as reference.  Sorry if this question is already answered.

Comment: Macro that deletes a cell depending on fill color?

Comment: Yes indeed, that's the major issue I got.

Comment: But! I want it to delete  let's say M500 AND C500 at the same time, according to M500 color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rewriting this answer as the requirement needs to iterate over any FormatCondition defined for each cell in the range as well as other values of cell. A neat method could be found, for example, [here](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/showthread.php/338-Get-Displayed-Cell-Color-(whether-from-Conditional-Formatting-or-not)). Basically, it consists of :

```
For X = 1 To Cell.FormatConditions.Count
    With Cell.FormatConditions(X)
      If .Type = xlCellValue Then
      ...
      If CellInterior Then
          DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, Cell.Interior.ColorIndex, Cell.Interior.Color)
        Else
          DisplayedColor = IIf(ReturnColorIndex, Cell.Font.ColorIndex, Cell.Font.Color)
```

Which explores the cell for different ways to define the filling Color.

So you should iterate over the range

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("M500:M550")
For Each cell In rng
   rem check the filling with the method in the link
   rem if it's the colorindex you want
   rem cell.Value = ''
   rem Also, get the row number and delete content of range ("C5XX")
Next cell
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Can you comment this (documenti it) a little so I can understand it a bit better? (Cause I am gonna use it a lot I suppose) more specifically I would like to know what
    Item(1)
refers to. What I want is to check column M for values, 500 to 550 for example that contain background color and if they don't then delete them and any data in C500 C500 for instance. How can I do that using this command?

Comment: Thank you so much!